# How do I initialize an array in this case?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am not sure I am doing what I think I am doing: I want to pass an array to a function in the following way:

```
void gauss(double**, double**, int)
int main(){
   double **a,**b;

   a=new double*[n];
   b=new double*[n];
   int n;
   ...
   gauss(a,b,n)
   ...
   return 0;}
void gauss(double**a, double**b,int n){...}
```

My problem is that I can't assign values to my array. I tried

```
a[0][0]=1;
a[0][1]=2;
a[1][0]=3;
a[1][1]=4;
```

but I get a segmentation violation error.

How do I assign value to my array in this case.

Comment: You have an "array" of pointers, but do you make these pointers actually point anywhere?

Comment: Also, I really recommend you start using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) whenever you need a "dynamic array".

Comment: once you fixed your code you should take a look at `std::vector`

Comment: He also seems to declare the variable n *after* he attempts to use it as the size of his arrays, so I'm not quite sure how this code can even compile...